# How to increase performance during bulk processing to Mongodb with Hibernate and Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

We are working with Hibernate over Spring Data JPA in an Spring MVC project to collect tweets having the next entities:

- Tweet: Has the tweet Id, a `@RelatedDocument` (Spring Data + MongoDB) and two manytomany relationships with Task and Bigram, is the owner of bigrams with persist and merge cascade types.
- Task: Has an Id and two manytomany relationships with Tweet and Bigram and is the owner of both, with persist and merge in tweet plus refresh and merge in bigrams.
- Bigram: Has an Id, a String and two manytomany relationships with Tweet and Task.

We are trying to process and store tweets for a given task in two ways:

- First way (memory problem), we process all tweets as follows:

  1. Create the tweet object based on the JSON received from streaming
     API.
  2. Get all bigrams related to the tweet's text and assign them like this

     ```
     task.getBigrams().add(bigram);
     bigram.getTasks().add(task);
     tweet.getBigrams().add(bigram);
     bigram.getTweets().add(tweet);
     ```
  3. Once the bigrams are processed we add the tweet object to task and vice versa

     ```
     tweet.getTasks().add(task);
     task.getTweets().add(tweet);
     ```
  4. And finally when we have processed all tweets we save the task.

As said, the problem with this aproach is that we can't handle all tweets in memory, since a task may be running for almost 15 minutes and we can get about 7000 tweets.

- Second way (performance problem), we process all tweets as follows:

Any time we process a tweet we save it, which causes multiple connections to be opened with mongodb and mysql, carrying a high delay (about 2-3 tweets per second).

So our questions are this:

1. What can be the cause of the delay specified in the second aproach?
2. Is there any way to get high performance without reaching outofmemory exceptions while working with big datasets?